# php to translate GET request to POST request

Tags: php

i have a hosted script somewhere that only accept POST request.
example, some.hosted/script.php

how can i setup another simple php that can accept GET request and then POST it to the hosted script.
so that i can put up a link like this:  other.site/post2hostedscript.php?postthis=data
and then it POST postthis=data to the hosted script.

tnx

edit:
post2hostedscript.php do not give any result.
the result will go directly to some.hosted/script.php
just as if the user POST directly at the hosted script.

Comment: And what is this script supposed to return after the GET request? The response of the other script after POST?

Comment: Why wouldn't a simple array_merge($_POST, $_GET) work? You can then call any scripts I would think. Not sure if any imminent issues.

Comment: Not a great idea. GET and POST are kind of meant to be separate so that user-agents know what they’re doing when they follow a link or post a form, i.e. following a link shouldn’t have side-effects, and issuing a GET request multiple times should have the same effect as issuing it once.

Answer (score 3):

Your `post2hostedscript.php` will have to :

- Fetch all parameters received as GET
- Construct a POST query
- Send it
- And, probably, return the result of that POST request.

This can probably be done using [curl](http://www.php.net/curl), for instance ; something like this should get you started :

```
$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.othersite.com/post2hostedscript.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $queryString);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

For a list of options that can be used with curl, you can take a look at the page of [`curl_setopt`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Here, you'll have to use, at least :

- `CURLOPT_POST` : as you want to send a POST request, and not a GET
- `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` : depending on whether you want `curl_exec` to return the result of the request, or to just output it.
- `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` : The data that will be posted -- i.e. what you have in the query string of your incoming request.

And note that the response from the POST request might include some interesting HTTP header -- if needed, you'll have to fetch them *(see the `CURLOPT_HEADER` option)*, and re-send the interesting ones in your own response *(see the [`header`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function)*.

Comment: +1 note though that GET data should not exceed 1024 bytes in size, and file uploads are impossible.

Comment: @Pekka : right about file uploads, and a limit on the size of GET *(Even though I would have said the limit is higher than 1k ; I would have said 2k on some browsers, and 32k on some others ? )*

Comment: @Pascal && @Pekka: Take a look at http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html - Anyways, personally i'd consider anything above 1024 bytes too long.

Comment: @Pascal I had saved 1k as a general limit in my head long ago, but it could be 2k.

Comment: i dont need upload etc. it's only a simple search-like query. the response should come directly from the hosted script. more like redirecting rather than proxying

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the "curl" functions, they provide everything you need.

Answer (score -1):

You might consider replacing all instances of $_POST in the old script to $_REQUEST, which will result in it accepting both GET and POST alike.